# need to fetch the data from sql with some text

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

i had a table with muliple rows and colums . i need a sql query to fetch the data with some text . i know the  row number  , but i dont the column name or column number . then how to write the sql for this

Comment: select * from tablename where rownumber = 123, to get all columns.

Comment: i need get the data only if the text matches

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve] is worth reading.)

Comment: BTW, are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: columns don't have numbers, they have names.  How is it you don't know the column name?  Knowing the names of tables and their columns is pretty fundamental to writing queries.  And I'm suspicious of your "knowing" a row number.  Rows don't really have numbers because they don't have any inherent ordering.  Row number is assigned to a row _as it is fetched_.  If you want rows in a particular order you _must_ use the ORDER BY clause in your query, and only in that specific result set will 'row number' have any meaning.